# Select/Deselect textfield using checkboxes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three text-fields and respective check boxes. When I select one check box corresponding text-field gets enabled.

I want to  hide all the other text-fields when I have already selected one check box and show all when I reselect the same check box.

I am confused about how to give id/class here and use them for the given problem.

Here is the jsfiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/ders/13kkpj1t/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//set initial state.
$("#checkbox2").click(function () {
    if ($("#checkbox2").prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#textbox2").attr("disabled", false);
        if ($(".cb1").prop('checked') == false) {
            $(".cb1").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    } else {
        $("#textbox2").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

**Note:- I want to hide all the other check boxes and text fields when I select one check box and again show them back when I deselect it.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a event handler to all the checkboxes then you want to disable/enable the next sibling element of the checked/unchecked checkbox so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //set initial state.
  $(".cb1").change(function() {
    $(this).next().prop('disabled', !this.checked)
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="cb1" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" disabled=true class="cb1" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="cb1" />
<input type="text" id="textbox3" disabled=true class="cb1" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="cb1" checked/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4" disabled=true class="cb1" />
<br />
```

Comment: That was not the problem, I wanted to hide all the other check boxes when I select one check box and again show them back when I deselect it.

Comment: @vidal then you want to disable all other textfields also?

Answer (score 2):

check with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //set initial state.
  $(":checkbox").change(function () {
     $(':text.cb').prop('disabled', this.checked);
     $(this).next(":text").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  });
});
```

1. Bind the `change` event on the checkboxes, jQuery has a `:checkbox` selector which selects all the checkboxes in a page.
2. `:text.cb` jQuery also has a specific selector to select all the text inputs with `:text` and `:text.cb` filters all the text inputs with a class name of `cb`.
3. Use `.prop(property, boolean)` method to disable all the text inputs.
4. and `this.checked` returns a boolean which is in the context of a checkbox so if checked returns `true` else `false`.
5. At the end just target your element and enable it with `!this.checked`

---

As per your latest comment:

If you can change your markup like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="cb1" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" disabled=true class="cb1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="cb1" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" disabled=true class="cb1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="cb1" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox4" disabled=true class="cb1" />
</div>
```

then you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //set initial state.
    $(":checkbox").change(function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings().toggle(!this.checked);
    });
});
```

#### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13kkpj1t/1/)

Comment: That was not the problem, I wanted to hide all the other check boxes when I select one check box and again show them back when I deselect it.

Comment: @vidal that isn't hard to implement just change the `.prop()` method to `.hide()` and `.show()` or `.toggle(this.checked)` and change the selector to the other checkboxes.